# How to refer to list view in Action Bar Android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I followed a tutorial and learned how to display a custom list right in the Action Bar.
The problem is that now I want to highlight (or select) a specific item in list programatically for example when user quits the app the app should take a note what was the last item the user has selected in the list (I can do that using shared preferences) and then when user opens my app again the list view should restore itself back to the last selected item.

I don't know how to select a item programatically in a custom list view. Maybe I have to reffer it first. But I don't know that also.

Here's my code :
**bus_names.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/busIcon"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/busTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Alaknanda"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**SpinnerNavItem.java :**

```
package com.hpubts50.hpubustracker.model;

public class SpinnerNavItem {

    private String title;
    private int icon;

    public SpinnerNavItem(String title, int icon){
        this.title = title;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return this.title;
    }

    public int getIcon(){
        return this.icon;
    }

}
```

**BusNavigation.java :**

```
package com.hpubts50.hpubustracker.adapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hpubts50.hpubustracker.R;
import com.hpubts50.hpubustracker.model.SpinnerNavItem;

public class BusNavigation extends BaseAdapter {
    private ImageView busIcon;
    private TextView busTitle;
    private ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem;
    private Context context;

    public BusNavigation(Context context, ArrayList<SpinnerNavItem> spinnerNavItem) {
        this.spinnerNavItem = spinnerNavItem;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return spinnerNavItem.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        return spinnerNavItem.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_names, parent, false);
        }

        busIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busIcon);
        busTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busTitle);

        busIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());
        busIcon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        busTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(ActionBarActivity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.bus_names, parent, false);
        }

        busIcon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busIcon);
        busTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.busTitle);

        busIcon.setImageResource(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getIcon());
        busTitle.setText(spinnerNavItem.get(position).getTitle());
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use getSupportActionBar() for getting action bar view